# How can I view all those users and their "Grants" for an entire table?

Tags: mysql, sql, privileges, sql-grant

If I have a table called example. And I grant privileges like SELECT, INSERT, etc to subject1, subject2, subject3. How can I then as the owner of the table, view everyone and their privileges that I have given to example?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a query against `tables_priv` table in the `mysql` database:

```
SELECT p.User
     , p.Host
     , p.Table_priv
     , p.Grantor
  FROM mysql.tables_priv p
 WHERE p.Db         = 'mydatabase'
   AND p.Table_name = 'example'
 ORDER by 1,2,3
```

This isn't everyone that has privileges on the table, if privileges were granted on the entire database, e.g.

```
GRANT SELECT ON mydatabase.* TO subject1@'%'
```

Those privileges would be in the `db` table in the `mysql` database. Global privileges granted to a user on all databases would be in the `user` table.

Answer (score 0):

The MySql schema for users and privileges is pretty vast complicated depending on how in depth you would like to get.

You can find all users from the [users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/users-table.html) table (granted you have permissions). And you may find table/column privileges from these two columns: [tables_priv and columns_priv](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant-table-structure.html#idm47263664421984)

so you would want something like this:

```
select * from users
join tables_priv on users.user = tables_priv.user
```

Take note that the more information you want, the more you will need to expand this query.

Comment: I would suggest that you read through the mysql documentation. It is pretty verbose.